# How to check for the type of a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have a template function and two classes

```
class animal {
}
class person {
}

template<class T>
void foo() {
  if (T is animal) {
    kill();
  }
}
```

How do I do the check for T is animal? I don't want to have
something that checks during the run time. Thanks

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Use `is_same`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void foo()
{
    if (std::is_same<T, animal>::value) { /* ... */ }  // optimizable...
}
```

Usually, that's a totally unworkable design, though, and you really want to *specialize*:

```
template <typename T> void foo() { /* generic implementation  */ }

template <> void foo<animal>()   { /* specific for T = animal */ }
```

Note also that it's unusual to have function templates with explicit (non-deduced) arguments. It's not unheard of, but often there are better approaches.

Comment: TThanks! Actually they share A LOT of code so I can not really duplicate it

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld: You can always factor your code so that the type-dependent part can be relegated to a specializable function...

Comment: One quick follow-up, if I do use std::is_same, then it will NOT slow down the code for other template parameters, right?

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld: The trait values are all statically known. There shouldn't be any runtime cost, provided your compiler is half-decent. Check the assembly if in doubt, though.

Comment: A question: if I only want to *specialize* the behaviour of the method for *one and only one* specific type, would using `C++11` default template parameters work as well?

Comment: @AdriC.S.: Since `T` isn't deduced, there's not much you can do. You could leave the primary template unimplemented and create a specialization, or you could add a static assertion with `is_same`.

Comment: How to know the type of the argument passed for primitive data types such as if int is passed or float is passed?

Comment: @Rajesh: how do you mean? The function `foo` has no parameters, so no arguments can be passed to it. You need to specify the template argument directly. And then the code in the answer can test for `int` and `float`, too (`is_same<T, int>` etc.).

Comment: Here is a link to the reference [`std::is_same`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_same/), I was missing it in the answer (but I don't think it's reason enough for an edit).

Comment: I had issues with `std::is_same` and `opencv` dataypes like `cv::Rect`. Is it possible, that `std::is_same` just supports default datatypes?

Comment: @MarkusDutschke What issue did you see using these datatypes with `std::is_same`? Can you describe what happened?

Answer (score 67):

I think todays, it is better to use, but this only works with C++17 or later.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void foo() {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, animal>) {
        // use type specific operations... 
    } 
}
```

If you use some type specific operations in if expression body without `constexpr`, this code will not compile.

Comment: could you elaborate on why this is better? is it performance or platform related?

Comment: Actually works. Ty!

Comment: @serup it's better, because it is new, and old things are always worse. `inline constexpr bool is_same_v = is_same<T, U>::value;` I have no clue why they keep adding these pointless "helpers" which only confuse people instead of fixing their broken language.

Answer (score 10):

`std::is_same()` is only available since C++11. For pre-C++11 you can use `typeid()`:

```
template <typename T>
void foo()
{
    if (typeid(T) == typeid(animal)) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can specialize your templates based on what's passed into their parameters like this:

```
template <> void foo<animal> {

}
```

Note that this creates an entirely new function based on the type that's passed as `T`. This is usually preferable as it reduces clutter and is essentially the reason we have templates in the first place.

Comment: Hmm. Is this method really the only preferable way to specialize template argument? Let's say I've 10 different child classes that I need to manage inside the template function. Do I really have to write 10 different template functions for respective class? I think I may be missing the core point here.

Comment: This really sounds like a good idea though, if someone doesn't want to use type_traits. Like someone mentioned the main logic can be done in a different function, which accepts an extra flag to indicate the type, and this specialized declaration can just set the flag accordingly and directly pass on all the other arguments without touching anything. So if 10 different classes need to be handled, it is basically 10 lines for 10 different function definitions. But this will get a lot complicated if there are more than 1 template variable.

Answer (score 7):

In C++17, we can use ***variants***.

To use `std::variant`, you need to include the header:

```
#include <variant>
```

After that, you may add `std::variant` in your code like this:

```
using Type = std::variant<Animal, Person>;

template <class T>
void foo(Type type) {
    if (std::is_same_v<type, Animal>) {
        // Do stuff...
    } else {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: How are T and Type connected?

Comment: This answer is problematic in several ways. Besides the actual errors (`type` which is the value of type `Type` or a template which does not make sense here) `is_same_v` is not meaningful in the context of `variant`. The corresponding "trait" is `holds_alternative`.

Comment: `std::variant` is totally unnecessary here

Answer (score 2):

use c++ concepts
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints

for example class who recive only char types

```
#include <concepts>

 template<typename Type>
    concept CharTypes = std::is_same<Type, char>::value ||
                        std::is_same<Type, wchar_t>::value || std::is_same<Type, char8_t>::value ||
                        std::is_same<Type, char16_t>::value || std::is_same<Type, char32_t>::value;

template<CharTypes T>
    class Some{};
```

and yes, this not working

```
    Some<int> s;
```