# call stoi when requesting int using template function

Tags: c++, templates

I have method which returns string, e.g. `returnString(std::string arg)`
I would like to have some wrapper function which will cast this function and return different types (and maybe do some further computation) based on how the wrapper function was called. I do not know how exactly this concept of requesting data type in templates is named so I will post example:

```
object->returnWrapper<int>(arg)    // return std::stoi(returnString(std::string arg))
object->returnWrapper<string>(arg) // return returnString(std::string arg)
object->returnWrapper(arg)         // return returnString(std::string arg)
```

The last one isn't mandatory, if there is need to always request desired type to explicitly get string I'm fine with that.

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636540/how-to-check-for-the-type-of-a-template-parameter) I've tried

```
template <>
int returnWrapper<int>(std::string arg) {
  return std::stoi(returnString(std::string arg))
}
```

but it VS intelisense says that returnWrapper is not a template

Comment: Is `returnWrapper` defined like `template <typename T>
int returnWrapper(std::string arg)`?

Comment: What are you asking exactly? How to create a default template argument? How to specialise a template? What? Present a [mcve] and a clear problem statement!

Comment: If this is all the code you have for `returnWrapper` then it is missing what NathanOliver mentioned. **Both** lines in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13636569/) you found are necessary!

Answer (score 2):

That's a [function template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization#Explicit_specializations_of_function_templates). You first need to declare the function template and then you can add specializations:

```
template <typename T = std::string>
T returnWrapper(std::string arg) {
    return returnString(arg);
}

template <>
int returnWrapper<int>(std::string arg) {
  return std::stoi(returnString(arg));
}
```

You can solve the problem more easily in C++17:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T = std::string>
T returnWrapper(std::string arg) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
        return std::stoi(returnString(arg));
    else
        return returnString(arg);
}
```

You should probably extract the converting functionality into a function that's independent of `returnString`.

Or you can use [`boost::lexical_cast`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html):

```
template <typename T>
T returnWrapper(std::string arg) {
    return boost::lexical_cast<T>(returnString(arg));
}
```

Comment: what does the `= std::string` in ```template <typename T = std::string>``` mean? Can I only write ```template <typename T>```?

Comment: @Ethanabc It means `std::string` is the default for `T`. It can be omitted.

Comment: @ krisz I appreciate your answer. It is very helpful.