c++ template only for some types
There are 2 types. Both has operator "[]".
How can I describe a function called with only these two types?
With typescrypt it looks like:
function func<T extends string|number[]>(arg: T) {
  return arg[0];
}

console.log(func([1]))


You can write a concept to check if the template parameter is either of those types.

Or just static_assert for the two types using std::is_same_v. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636540/how-to-check-for-the-type-of-a-template-parameter or How to check for the existence of a subscript operator?

Write two functions, one for each type. Put common code in a third function that each can call.

Reopened. The purported duplicates addressed two narrower issues.

please do not add the answer to the quesiton. You can write an answer in the answer section though

It is very bad to pass eigen objects by value. The modern way is to take a Eigen::Ref. You should read the Eigen documentation thoroughly and if you come across another question related to Eigen, ask a new question about it.

@WeijunZhou thanks. I know that it is a deep copy. Just for example.

Nowadays, you wouldn't need to make it a template, and could use overloading instead:
char func(std::string_view arg) {
  return arg[0];
}

int func(std::span<const int> arg) {
  return arg[0];
}

This does cover two separate types effectively.
However, it feels somewhat arbitrary that only std::string_view and std::span are supported, when this function looks like a "get first element" function that should work with any range.
A more general solution would be to write a template as follows:
template <std::range R>
std::ranges::range_value_t<R> func(R&& r) {
    return *std::ranges::begin(std::forward<R>(r));
}

This is arguably better because it gives you a copy of the first element of any range, including std::vector, std::forward_list, etc.

In common case it can be combination of template and overload:
template <typename T>
bool func(T vec) {
// ...
}
template bool func(std:string& vec);
template bool func(double* vec);
template bool func(Eigen::VectorXi& vec);
template bool func(Eigen::RowVectorXi& vec);

Thanks, @PeteBecker, @JanSchulke.
